# Variable looks like a function pointer

Tags: c, scope, function-declaration

```c
char *getoccupier(int roomno)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    int j;
    char *getoccupier(int), *p;

    for (j = 1; j <= NROOMS; j++)
    {
        if (p == getoccupier(j))
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

In the main function I saw

> ```
> *getoccupier(int)
> ```

variable.

I thought it was function pointer but I don't think it is.

Function pointer needs "()" like `(*getoccupier)(int)` but it doesn't have it.

What is that?

Comment: Rather than to tell us what you saw, could you post the actual code? Because `*getoccupier(int)` is not valid C.

Comment: The one in main is a function prototype.

Comment: @Lundin ? This code compiles perfectly well

Comment: @klutt The question is about some `*getoccupier(int)` code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters its seems you mean

```
if ( ( p = getoccupier(j) )){
```

or

```
if ( ( p = getoccupier(j) ) != NULL ){
```

instead of

```
if (p == getoccupier(j)){
```

Within the function main

```
char *getoccupier(int), *p;
```

there is a block scope function declaration of the function getoccupier.

The function declaration has external linkage though the linkage specifier extern is absent. So you may have several declarations of the same function.

Pay attention to that parameter names may be omitted in a function declaration that is not at the same time the function definition.

Also in one declaration you may declare several declarators as for example

```
char c, *s, f( int );
```

where there are declared an object `c` of the type `char`, the pointer `s` of the type `char *` and the function `f` of the type `char( int )`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello( void ) { puts( "Hello"); }

int main(void) 
{
    hello();
    
    int hello = 10;

    printf( "Hello = %d\n", hello );

    {   
        void hello( void );
    
        hello();
    }
    
    printf( "Hello = %d\n", hello );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello
Hello = 10
Hello
Hello = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`char *getoccupier(int), *p;` declares `getoccupier` to be a function taking an `int` argument and returning a pointer to a `char` (a `char *`), and it declares `p` to be a pointer to a `char`.